# how remotely connect to sql server 2008-r2 installed on vps(virtual private network)? (firewall and sql server 2008 configs)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, remote-access, sql-server-2008-r2

i have sql server 2008 r2 installed on a virtual private network (vps) with one ip valid ...
my sql server instance info for connect on server(vps) is like below :
`server type: database engine

server name : ServerComputerName\InstanceName

Authentication : sql server

login : sa

password : blablabla`

================================================

how can i connect to that sql server instance from my pc (remotely server access for backup) ?
*which changes are necessary in windows firewall and node32 firewall on server?
*also which changes are necessary in sql server 2008 r2 for remote access?
*which sotware is the best for remotely connect to that instance?

`server type: database engine

server name : ????\????

Authentication : sql server

login : sa

password : blablabla`

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any experience with SQL Server at all?  If not, I would suggest you setup a local instance on your workstation to play with first before opening up your VPS instance to the Internet.

Comment: Do you have any experience with SQL Server at all? -> yes , i am working with it in my local machine! but, what is your poit?

Comment: my point is you're asking very basic questions, which is fine if you're working in a development or lab/learning setup, but a VPS is not the place to learn how to setup SQL for remote connections.

Comment: is there any problem for learning and practicing with vps and asking questions about that ? although i think vps is nothing , just a virtual server created with vmvare and some people imagine that , it is only for professional people ... i do not know nothing about network (just a system web developer and web designer) / but i forced to config my server by myself!

Comment: i disabled my nod32 and could connect to that sql server instance (ip-address\instance name), but i do n't know which changes are necessary in eset nod32 for opening that remote connection!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question *which changes are necessary in windows firewall and node32 firewall on server?* you should open port TCP 1433 on both your windows firewall and NOD32 (I guess you mean ESET Smart Security - because NOD32 is antivirus only).

*also which changes are necessary in sql server 2008 r2 for remote access?* 
To enable remote access on SQL Server 2008 you need to enable TCP/IP from the SQL Configuration Manager and restart the SQL Service to apply changes.
Screenshot: http://georgetasioulis.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/enable-tcpip-sql-server.png

Also I would suggest you switch to SQL Server and Windows authentication mode.
This can be done from the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio by right clicking on the SQL server instance, selecting "Properties" and the "Security" on the left window.
Screenshot: http://georgetasioulis.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/sql-authentication-mode.jpg

Finally regarding your third question *which sotware is the best for remotely connect to that instance?* I would stick with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. No need to go to any 3rd party software solution.

Comment: thanks for clear answer and help without any unrelated stuff...